# javascript for web page, next-prev image

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i found a scrip for switching images on a web site and i am having problems to make it work.
The images swith fine until you get to the fourth, i added 6 but it get stucks there. Here is the code if somebody can tell me where is the problem.

thanks!

```
var myImg= new Array(5)
  myImg[0]= "recientes1";
  myImg[1]= "recientes2";
  myImg[2]= "recientes3";
  myImg[3]= "recientes4";
  myImg[4]= "recientes5";
  myImg[5]= "recientes6";

myImgSrc = "recientes/";

myImgEnd = ".jpg"

var i = 0;

function loadImg(){
  document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[i] + myImgEnd;
}

function prev(){
  if(i<1){
    var l = i
  } else {
    var l = i-=1;
  }
  document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[l] + myImgEnd;
}

function next(){
  if(i>2){
    var l = i
  } else {
    var l = i+=1;
  }
  document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[l] + myImgEnd;
}

window.onload=loadImg;
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var myImg= new Array(5)
  myImg[0]= "recientes1";
  myImg[1]= "recientes2";
  myImg[2]= "recientes3";
  myImg[3]= "recientes4";
  myImg[4]= "recientes5";
  myImg[5]= "recientes6";

myImgSrc = "recientes/";

myImgEnd = ".jpg";

var i = 0;
loadImg();

function loadImg(){
  document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[i] + myImgEnd;
}

function prev(){
  i=(i<=0)?myImg.length-1:i-1;
  loadImg();
}

function next(){
  i=(i>=myImg.length-1)?0:i+1;
  loadImg();
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/89YAH/1/)

**Additionnal info**

`i=(i>=myImg.length-1)?0:i+1;`

can be translated as

```
if( i >= myImg.length-1 ){ i = 0; }
else{ i = i+1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The if block in the next() function seems to stop it from proceeding further (it reached the end of the list). You should change this from 2 to something like myImg.length - 1 to make sure that it doesn't go further than the amount of images you have.

```
function next(){   
    if(i>myImg.length-1){
        var l = i   
    } else {
        var l = i+=1;   
    }   
    document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[l] + myImgEnd; 
}
```

If you want the next() function to go to the beginning of the list when you hit the end, you would have to modify your next() function to reset i to zero. Something like this:

```
function next(){   
    if(i>myImg.length-1){
        i = 0;
        var l = i; 
    } else {
        var l = i+=1;   
    }   
    document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[l] + myImgEnd; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator to do this very cleanly and simply...

```
function prev(){
    i = (i - 1) % myImg.length - 1;
    document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[i] + myImgEnd;
}

function next(){
    i = (i + 1) % myImg.length - 1;
    document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[l] + myImgEnd;
}
```

The `%` basically makes the number passed to it has to be between 0 and the number after it.  So, with an array of length 6, it will only allow numbers between 0 and 5.  -1 becomes 5 and 6 becomes 0.

**[See here for more information on the modulus (remainder) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)**

Comment: Modulus has higher precedence than `+` & `-` so your code is doing `i-(1 % myImg.length)-1`! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks - modified to suit :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your array length is initialized to 5 then you are adding 6 entries.

When you define the length of an array (i.e. `new Array(5)`) you are saying that there will be 5 entries in the array which will have indexes of 0, 1, 2, 3, & 4.  Your code will end up creating an array of length 6 which looks like what you want, but thought it was worth noting because if you try to find myImg[myImg.length] it won't find anything.

How are your prev and next functions being called?